# Only get non-filtered values for Google App Script getRange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is there a way to only get non-filtered values only in Google App Script? (i.e. get values that are showing and not hidden ones?

For example, let’s say I have the following cells + values in Google Sheets.

```
A1=abc    B1=x
A2=def    B2=y
A3=ghi    B3=y
A4=kjl    B4=x
```

And I filtered B column so it only displays [y].

```
A2=def    B2=y
A2=ghi    B3=y
```

When I use the following script, both hidden and non-hidden values gets printed to the msgBox.

```
function msgBoxTest(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
var range_input = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var result = [i for each (i in range_input)if (isNaN(i))]; 
// remove commas originating from empty cells

Browser.msgBox(result);  
//I want only def & ghi to display here. 
//Instead, I get all values -> abc,def,ghi,kjl
}
```

I've googled and looked online but couldn't find code about filtering out values in Google App script. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to to use script, this will do it:

```
function msgBoxTest(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
var range = ss.getRange("A1:B").getValues();
var filter=[]//new array
  for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
   if (range[i][1]=="y"){
    filter.push(range[i][0])
  }}
Browser.msgBox(filter);  
//I want only def & ghi to display here. 
}
```

Or you could do it with a simple query formula:

```
=query(A1:B,"Select A where B='y'")
```

Comment: Hi Ed, this is very close to what I was seeking. Thank you!!! 

I am thinking this is 90% what I was seeking for (the script portion)
Wondering if it's possible to filter without a second column (maybe I shouldn't have used the column B+'y' in the example)

For example, let's say there was only column A and no column B. 
Can you still think of a way to grab only non-filtered data?

Comment: Could you give an example? Perhaps ask a new question.

Comment: Actually reading through the suggestion, I think slightly modifying it would work. So please kindly ignore my last message. Again, thanks for your advice, very helpful.