# Only get non-filtered values for Google App Script getRange using isRowHiddenByFilter or isRowHiddenByUser

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new, trying to do the same thing as [Only get non-filtered values for Google App Script getRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616109/only-get-non-filtered-values-for-google-app-script-getrange)
- get all rows that aren't hidden without using an added column.  Make it generic so that regardless of what fields were used to hide rows, I'll only be acting on the non-hidden.  I've been playing with isRowHiddenByFilter() and isRowHiddenByUser() but not getting it.  To get all unfiltered rows, would I need to check that isRowHiddenByFilter() and isRowHiddenByUser() are both false?

It seems like the above should work with something like (not sure how the NOT is specified):

```
  for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){
   if (NOT range.isRowHiddenByFilter){
    filter.push(range[i][0])
  }}
```

Comment: `NOT` is `!` `````````````````​`````````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Get All values and use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out hidden rows

#### Sample script:

```
const getVisibleValues_ = (shtName, rngString, sheet, range) => {
  sheet = sheet || SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shtName);
  return (range || sheet
    .getRange(rngString))
    .getValues()
    .filter(
      (_, rowIdx) =>
        !sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(rowIdx + 1) &&
        !sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(rowIdx + 1)
    );
};

const test1 = () => console.info(getVisibleValues_('Sheet1', 'B1:B70'));
```

Comment: This looks good - I'm digesting, having a little trouble. JavaScript is very confusing compared to VBA which I know well.  How do you pass arguments such as sheets?  What type is returned?

Comment: @user363 `test1` shows how to pass sheets as strings . It returns a 2D array

Comment: I'm not getting it.  I can't call the function.  My sheet and range are defines via: let sheetx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() and var range_input = sheetx.getRange(1, 1, sheetx.getLastRow(), sheetx.getLastColumn());  Trying to call the functin with all combinations of single quotes, double quotes, lets, vars doesn't work.  I'm trying to get an array I can feed to more code.

Comment: @user363 If the first sheet is `Sheet1` and the range is A1:F50, try `const test1 = () => console.info(getVisibleValues_('Sheet1', 'A1:F50'));`. You'll get the data in your log after you run `test1`.

Comment: @user modified the script to accept sheet/range objects as well. `const sheetx = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();const range_input = sheetx.getRange(1, 1, sheetx.getLastRow(), sheetx.getLastColumn()); const test2 = () => console.info(getVisibleValues_(null, null, sheetx, range_input));`

Comment: Test2 comes up null when I log references to it.  Why is console needed?  How can I do something very simple like use the function to populate test2 then compare to a value in it?

Comment: @user `const test2 = getVisibleValues_(null, null, sheetx, range_input);`

Comment: This works great!  Sorry I was so slow on the uptake.  Learning!  :)